# Comparar string ignorando letras maiúsculas/minúsculas C#

Tags: c#

Como verificar se duas strings são iguais ignorando as letras maiúsculas e minúsculas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
firstString.Equals(secondString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```